# Rewrite 301 index.php to / on htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do redirect with index.php/index.html to / but when I added this code on the top:

```
RewriteRule ^index.(php|html|htm)$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/index.(php|html|htm)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

my current code doesn't work property:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#301

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.pl(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.pl/$1 [R=301,L]


#STRONA

#Pojedyncza Oferta - jezyki
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3&title=$4 [L]

#Aktualnosci, Oferta i Galeria - jezyki
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&bookmarkTitle=$3 [L]

#Linki - jezyki
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]

#Pojedyncza Oferta
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2&title=$3 [L]

#Aktualnosci, Oferta i Galeria
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1&bookmarkTitle=$2 [L]

#Linki
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch MSIE ie
        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

After adding above code I got:
domain.pl/page?kontakt instead of domain.pl/kontakt.html

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this rule for `index` removal **just below `RewriteEngine On` line**:

```
# remove index.php or index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(?:php|html?)$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but could you tell me why did you use 302 instead of 301?

Comment: `302` was only for testing, you can change it to 301 now